# Limit of an equation similar to the Euler's constant definition

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} = ?  $$

I don't know even how to start this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look at it. It blows up.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

And fast! It's bigger than $2^n$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $2+1/n > 2 $ for all $n$, we have $(2+1/n)^n > 2^n$ for each $n$, so the sequence tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\left[1+\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left[1+\frac{1}{n}\right]^k\geq\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\infty$$